# Android - Retrofit2 - 403-Forbidden

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am creating an application with retrofit2 for network calls. I need call multiple API in Single Activity. Now I am facing the **403-forbidden** error. If I call only one API it is working fine. But if I use multiple API calls one by one then I am facing this error.

My CreateService method is below:

```
public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass, final String authToken) {
        if (authToken != null) {
            httpClient.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    Request original = chain.request();

                    // Request customization: add request headers
                    Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                            .header("Authorization-Token", authToken)
                            .method(original.method(), original.body());

                    Request request = requestBuilder.build();
                    return chain.proceed(request);
                }
            });
        }

//        OkHttpClient client = httpClient.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();
        Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(200));
        dispatcher.setMaxRequests(200);
        dispatcher.setMaxRequestsPerHost(1);

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = httpClient.dispatcher(dispatcher).connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(100, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).build();

        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(okHttpClient).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
```

What is wrong in my code.. How can I handle this?

Comment: is there any dependency on waiting on first api call to complete before kicking off 2nd one?

Comment: No all the API have different data. No relation with that

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that string is not empty string?

Could you please add log interceptor and set the log level and provide a log?

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
```

And sth like this :

```
OkHttpClient.Builder okBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    okBuilder.addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC).setLevel
            (HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY).setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS))
```

Comment: How to set authorization-token with this?

Comment: Not at all with this. Use your code with this will provide a log, and we can see where is the problem.

Comment: Ok. My log <-- 403 Forbidden http://x.y.z/api/Technicians (976ms)
 Cache-Control: no-cache
 Pragma: no-cache
 Content-Length: 17
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
 Expires: -1
 Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
 Date: Thu, 15 Dec 2016 12:27:27 GMT
 <-- END HTTP
 <-- 403 Forbidden http://x.y.z/api/Technicians

Comment: For all the API result same as above

Comment: Any clue.. :). Have you find anything?

Comment: I am using the same tutorial what is wrong in my code?